# Am I Leaking ADO.NET Connections?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, ado.net, sql-server-2000

Here is an example of my code in a DAL. All calls to the database's Stored Procedures are structured this way, and there is no in-line SQL.

```
Friend Shared Function Save(ByVal s As MyClass) As Boolean

    Dim cn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = Dal.Connections.MyAppConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

    Try
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "proc_save_my_class"

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", s.Foo)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", s.Bar)

        Return True

    Finally
        Dal.Utility.CleanupAdoObjects(cmd, cn)
    End Try

End Function
```

Here is the Connection factory (if I am using the correct term):

```
Friend Shared Function MyAppConnection() As SqlClient.SqlConnection

    Dim cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ToString)
    cn.Open()

    If cn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        ' CriticalException is a custom object inheriting from Exception.
        Throw New CriticalException("Could not connect to the database.")
    Else
        Return cn
    End If

End Function
```

Here is the Dal.Utility.CleaupAdoObjects() function:

```
Friend Shared Sub CleanupAdoObjects(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand, ByVal cn As SqlConnection)
    If cmd IsNot Nothing Then cmd.Dispose()
    If cn IsNot Nothing AndAlso cn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Close()
End Sub
```

I am getting a lot of "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." error messages reported by the users. The application's DAL opens a connection, reads or saves data, and closes it. No connections are ever left open - intentionally!

There is nothing obvious on the Windows 2000 Server hosting the SQL Server 2000 that would indicate a problem. Nothing in the Event Logs and nothing in the SQL Server logs.

The timeouts happen randomly - I cannot reproduce. It happens early in the day with only 1 to 5 users in the system. It also happens with around 50 users in the system. The most connections to SQL Server via Performance Monitor, for all databases, has been about 74.

The timeouts happen in code that both saves to, and reads from, the database in different parts of the application. The stack trace does not point to one or two offending DAL functions. It's happened in many different places.

Does my ADO.NET code appear to be able to leak connections? I've goolged around a bit, and I've read that if the connection pool fills up, this can happen. However, I'm not explicitly setting any connection pooling. I've even tried to increase the Connection Timeout in the connection string, but timeouts happen long before the 300 second (5 minute) value:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=300;"/>
```

I'm at a total loss already as to what is causing these Timeout issues. Any ideas are appreciated.

**EDIT:** This is a WinForms application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33167/1954):

> Unlike Finalize, developers should call Dispose explicitly to free unmanaged resources. In fact, you should call the Dispose method explicitly on any object that implements it to free any unmanaged resources for which the object may be holding references.

`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader`, etc... all implement `IDisposable`. If you enclose all these instances in a Using block, then `Dispose` will be called automatically, your connections will be closed, and you won't have to worry about issues like this. Fire up Reflector and take a look for yourself: (`SqlConnection.Dispose`)

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        this._userConnectionOptions = null;
        this._poolGroup = null;
        this.Close();
    }
    this.DisposeMe(disposing);
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

This also makes the code shorter in that you don't have to manually add a Finally block to clean up your ADO.NET objects.

```
Using connection As SqlConnection("your connection string")
    Using command As New SqlCommand("your sql", connection)
        connection.Open()
        Using dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            'Your stuff here
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Using the `Using` approach forces you to keep your ADO.NET objects local, which to me is a good thing.

Comment: Is there a VB.NET equivalent to Using? I don't think VB.NET's With ... End With works like C#'s Using. EDIT: Maybe I should read your posted code closer ... VB.NET Using ;)

Comment: If I am opening my connection in my "connection factory" function, and then enclose the local connection variable in a Using (while already open), I eliminate opening the connection after "Using command". Will "Using connection" still close the connection, even though it was opened in the connection factory function?

Comment: VB.NET has the Using statement as of the 2.0 framework. Using simply translates into a Try Finally block, with Dispose being called in the Finally. Using Reflector, we can see that the Dispose method of SqlConnection calls Close(). It doesn't matter that the object is actually created in your factory class. It will be wrapped in a Finally block and Close will be called. That's be beauty of Using. It ensures that your objects are calling Dispose(), which in this case also ensures that your connection will be closed.

Comment: Good info. I'll have to reconstruct the code next release, and I'm implementing this style in my new project.

Answer (score 3):

One way to check for connection leaks is to add `max pool size` to the connection string, like:

```
"integrated security=SSPI;server=MyHost;Max Pool Size=1;"
```

In development I usually run with this setting (or size 2 if the application uses two connections simultaneously.)

Comment: Very good idea. I'm only using at most two connections. The search feature runs on a BackgroundWorder control.

Answer (score 1):

You should always Dispose the Connection, regardless of its State:

```
 'If cn IsNot Nothing AndAlso cn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Close()
 If cn IsNot Nothing Then cn.Dispose()
```

I'm not sure it this could cause your timeouts but it certainly is an improvement.

Comment: I e-mailed Scott Guthrie about this once, who referred the issue to someone else at Microsoft. The result was that .Close() implicitly calls .Dispose(). However, do you think my check on cn.State could be causing trouble?

Comment: Yes, the guideline is: Close == Dispose, and therefore a matter of taste. But you may be keeping a Closed connection from being returned to the pool.

Comment: I change the code to use Dispose(), and as Andomar suggested, set the Max Pool Size to two (times out due to the connection pool, which isn't the error reported by users) and then to three which does not throw a connection pool error. I am opening and closing many connections consecutively, but none in this case are simultaneous.

Answer (score 0):

How do your stored procedures perform outside of your application?

What if you moved the 'return true' out of your try/finally block in Save()?

Monitor DB connections in perf monitor to see if they grow.

But the first place I would look is your sprocs themselves - do they access tables in consistent order or might you be running into locks? For example, if proc1 manipulates table1 and then table2, while proc2 hits table2 and then table1 you might run into locking issues.

Comment: Stored Procedures perform instantaneously - mostly just CRUD operations. I've explicitly set the Command Timeout much higher for the SPs that search the database, etc. These timeouts are happening on instantaneous "add one new row to a table" queries.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a windows app or a web app?

Do the timeouts happen with simple stored procedures or just with more complicated ones?

Have you tried running a sql profiler trace to see if any queries really are taking a long time?

Also, have you tried converting to the "using" syntax, which ensures that the objects get closed and disposed of properly?

Comment: It is a Windows application. I've ran the SQL Profiler for adverse events such as errors on connections, but nothing showed. I can't use "using" as this is VB.NET.

Comment: If you are using visual studio 2005 or above, using is a VB keyword. I use it all the time.

Comment: I wonder if you have threading issues. You mentioned that some search features are being done in a Background worker. This is just a hunch, but I think that Shared and multi-threading are not playing nicely together. ADO.NET cannot read from 2 connections simultaneously unless you have MARS enabled.

Comment: This would be an issue only if a user was both searching and performing another DB calling function? No one so far has reported that (I wish it were that specific a time when the timeouts happen!)

Comment: *slaps forehead* I never realized that Using was added to VB.NET. I'll give it a try.